# Why can't openssl verify signature created by Python cryptography library?

Tags: python, openssl, cryptography, rsa, signing

I have created a signature of a file using the Python cryptography library as per this [1] link. This is the snippet I'm using (I've omitted the part where I serialize the signature to a file.

```
>>> from cryptography.hazmat.primitives import hashes
>>> from cryptography.hazmat.primitives.asymmetric import padding
>>> message = b"A message I want to sign"
>>> signature = private_key.sign(
...     message,
...     padding.PSS(
...         mgf=padding.MGF1(hashes.SHA256()),
...         salt_length=padding.PSS.MAX_LENGTH
...     ),
...     hashes.SHA256()
... )
```

Problem is that when I try to verify the signature file using the `openssl` CLI, it fails:

```
openssl dgst -sha256 \
> -signature sig.sha256 \
> -verify pubkey.pem \
> -sigopt rsa_padding_mode:pss \
> -sigopt rsa_pss_saltlen:-1 \
> -sigopt rsa_mgf1_md:sha256 \
> myfile
Verification Failure
```

I'm not sure what else to check here. Assuming I'm doing everything else correctly, the only thing I'm not 100% confident about is whether my `openssl` flags are correct. Perhaps they aren't matching the settings of the signing process done in cryptography?

[1] https://cryptography.io/en/latest/hazmat/primitives/asymmetric/rsa/#signing

EDIT: Fix is to either remove `-sigopt rsa_pss_saltlen` altogether or set it to `-sigopt rsa_pss_saltlen:-2`, which sets the salt length to be based on the PSS block structure (as per https://www.openssl.org/docs/man1.0.2/man1/pkeyutl.html).

Comment: Usually the problem is rather in the encoding of the message, e.g. a byte order mark, other encoding or line ending.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I created the following sign.py script based on the Python crypto library you referenced:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python

from cryptography.hazmat.backends import default_backend
from cryptography.hazmat.primitives import serialization
from cryptography.hazmat.primitives import hashes
from cryptography.hazmat.primitives.asymmetric import padding
import sys
import os

with open("./private.pem", "rb") as key_file:
    private_key = serialization.load_pem_private_key( key_file.read(),
        password=None, backend=default_backend())

with open(sys.argv[1], "r") as file_to_sign:
    message = file_to_sign.read()
    message = message.encode()

signature = private_key.sign( message, padding.PSS(
                mgf=padding.MGF1(hashes.SHA256()),
                salt_length=padding.PSS.MAX_LENGTH), hashes.SHA256())
sigfile = "%s.%s" % (os.path.splitext(sys.argv[1])[0] , "sig")
with open(sigfile, "wb") as to_sig_file:
    to_sig_file.write(signature)
```

I then created a text file, message.txt, with your message in there and generated the signature as such:

```
./sign.py message.txt
```

The output of this script is the signature in the file `message.sig`

I was able to successfully verify it using the following openssl command:

```
openssl dgst -sha256 -verify public.pem -signature message.sig -sigopt \
rsa_padding_mode:pss  message.txt
Verified OK
```

Comment: Thanks. Fixed after I removed the following flag from the openssl command "-sigopt rsa_pss_saltlen:-1".

Comment: thnx for this answer. this saved my day!